# ANSIBLE how tofix misspelled module name openssh_keypair

Tags: ansible

For this task:

```
  - name: "Generate ssh keypair"
    openssh_keypair:
      path: /tmp/ddd_id_rsa
```

Get this error:

```
ERROR! no action detected in task. This often indicates a misspelled module name, or incorrect module path.
```

How to fix this trouble(the other tasks at same playbook works fine)?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use a module from a pre-release version of Ansible. You will either need to wait for the feature to be released (in 2.8, according to the docs) or run the git branch of ansible in which it is being developed.

Answer (score 0):

I just use other module:

```
  - name: "GENERATE KEY"
    user:
      name: "user"
      generate_ssh_key: yes
      ssh_key_bits: 2048
      ssh_key_file: "~/.ssh/id_rsa"
    register: keyfile
```